# Django-jython war file deployment

Tags: django, jython

Trying to create a war file from my django program, keep running into this error when running `jython manage.py war`:

```
jython manage.py war --include-java-libs "/home/user/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/doj/backends/zxjdbc/mysql/base.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.features = DatabaseFeatures()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a known bug, hopefully taken care of soon.

http://code.google.com/p/django-jython/issues/detail?id=56&q=mysql